# AngularJS $scope.$watch for element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code inside my .haml file with Angular:

```
  %li.dropdown{"ng-repeat" => "region in regions"}
        %a{:href => "#"}
          %input{:type => "checkbox", "ng-model" => "PODLocation", "ng-true-value" => "filter", "ng-false-value" => "noFilter"}/
          %span.lbl {{region.toUpperCase()}}
```

The Following inside the AngularJS Controller:

```
   $scope.regions = [
        'am',
        'cn',
        'uk',
        'au',
        'ru'
    ];


   # Controls when the user selects options from dropdown menu
    $scope.$watch 'PODLocation', (value) ->
        console.log "In Search Location Watch"
        console.log "Inside Watch"
        switch value
          when "filter"
            $scope.search.location = region
          when "no-filter"
            $scope.search.location = ""
```

But it seems like no matter how i debug it, the $scope.$watch does not get invoked upon every click of the list of checkboxes (IE: Console.log messages do not appear upon each click). Furthermore, it seems like I can select multiple checkboxes at the same time (which should not occur since angular binds them to the same PODLocation variable).

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: `ngRepeat` creates a child scope for each item. You need to write to `PODLocation` on the parent scope.

Comment: Any suggestions to achieve the result that I am trying to get?

Comment: Try `"ng-model" => "$parent.PODLocation"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as all the checkboxes seem to binded together (checking one checkbox will check them all). I only want to check off 1 checkbox at once and filter based on that.

Comment: If they're mutually exclusive you should consider radios instead.

Comment: This still doesnt really help me...